# How to build an Angular2 type script with spring boot back end in STS

Tags: spring-boot

I am learning angular 2 currently and trying to hosted in springboot java application.

I created a separate project using angular cli , then I created spring starter project with web only.

Next I imported the angular cli project inside /src/main/resources/static directory.

when I opened the browser , I was not able to see the basic index.html.

Then I removed all the imported files and imported only the content of the  directory , which is the resulting compiled ES5 java script after transpiling the type script files in  directory, this time it worked.

My questions are:-

1) What is the best practice , to use the GUI under /src/main/statis or create /src/main/public or /src/main/webapp ?

2) Does spring understand only js and not ts ( java script and not type script)?

3) Do I need a maven plugin for typescript and if so how to tell maven bundle the compiled js with the spring war while excluding the rest directories and files

4) How to include the testing unit / e2e with maven build

I searched for step by step guide for ANgular 2 and spring boot but could not find one. It would be helpful to many if some guide like this exist.

Many thanks for your support guys.

Answer (score 1):

1) What is the best practice , to use the GUI under /src/main/statis or create /src/main/public or /src/main/webapp ?

**Since typescript compiles to JavaScript I strongly recommend using GULP. I have my source files under src/client and I build with gulp to add the files to src/main/public**

**I believe either public or webapp works and there's not a huge difference.**

2) Does spring understand only js and not ts ( java script and not type script)?

**The newer version of STS has support for typescript, but I prefer to use visual studio code when viewing typescript files as there is better support.**

3) Do I need a maven plugin for typescript and if so how to tell maven bundle the compiled js with the spring war while excluding the rest directories and files

**If you use gulp, the typescript is compiled to js and added to the src/main/public directory where your springboot app sees the files when running with maven.**

4) How to include the testing unit / e2e with maven build

I searched for step by step guide for ANgular 2 and spring boot but could not find one. It would be helpful to many if some guide like this exist.

Many thanks for your support guys.

**I recommend using an angular seed or starter, this seems like the most up to date one that I've found:
https://github.com/antonybudianto/angular2-starter
This uses gradle, but is spring boot and angular 2:
https://github.com/borysn/spring-boot-angular2**

Answer (score 0):

I shared a project on github that integrates Angular 2 With spring boot. Just need to follow the step on readme or check commit history. You can access here [Angular 2 with spring boot](https://github.com/mauriciolassakoski/angular_2_springboot)